# Backbone.js collection wont fetch models that arent valid

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, coffeescript

I added a validation to a Model and a Collection wont fetch the models who arent valid. (Btw I use coffeescript so the examples are in coffeescript)

Somebody knows a solution for this? The following isnt working

```
collection = new UserCollection

collection.fetch({
  silent: true
  success: ->
    console.log('collection.models:', collection.models)
})
```

UPDATE 1

I have a lot of users without a mobile number.

User Collection:

```
class UserCollection extends Backbone.Collection

  url: ->
    app.routes.users_url
```

User Model:

```
class User extends Backbone.Model

  idAttribute: '_id'

  defaults: {
    "email": null
    "mobile": null
    "loc": null
  }

  url: ->
    app.routes.users_url + '/' + (@id || '')

  validate: (attrs) ->
    if !attrs.email
      return "Email address must be provided"
    if !attrs.name
      return "Name must be provided"
    if !attrs.mobile
      return "Mobile number must be provided"
    if @isNew() and attrs.password != undefined
      if !attrs.password
        return "Password must be provided"
      if attrs.password != attrs.password_confirmation
        return "Passwords do not match"
  model: User
```

UPDATE 2

ok i temporary fixed it by hacking the backbone.js.

It is happening in function _prepareModel

I changed this line:

```
if (model.validate && !model._performValidation(attrs, options)) model = false;
```

into this line:

```
if (!options.silent && model.validate && !model._performValidation(attrs, options)) model = false;
```

It is not a solution so i keep this question open

Comment: Have you tried passing an `error` callback as well? Does it get called?

Comment: can you post your model and validation code?

Comment: Odd... The Collections.fetch function won't run your validators if you pass in the `silent: true` flag.  Are you sure your `validate` function is being called?  http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-30

Comment: @BrianGenisio Please check my UPDATE 2. The function is called in _prepareModel. Even if you pass the silent:true. Could this be a bug? Or do I do something wrong? Maybe it is good to open an issue on github for this

Answer (score 0):

```
"I added a validation to a Model and a Collection wont fetch the models who arent valid.
(Btw I use coffeescript so the examples are in coffeescript)"
```

If your models don't validate you have a problem with your models or your validation.

```
"I have a lot of users without a mobile number."
```

In your validation you have:

```
if !attrs.mobile
  return "Mobile number must be provided"
```

you could define a parse function in your collection to log what models are coming from the server (parse() gets passed the raw response from fetch())

```
parse: function(response) {
  console.log(response.results);
  return response.results;
}
```

or you can take the line that validates the existence of a mobile number out of your validation since you don't know if the user has a mobile number.

and just to cover all the bases, defining an error function for fetch() should help you:

```
collection.fetch({
  silent: true
  success: ->
    console.log('collection.models:', collection.models)
  error: (collection, response) ->
    console.log('response')
})
```

Comment: The problem was, even if i added silent:true, the collection didnt fetch them.

Comment: Worth noting that the `parse` method within a Collection doesn't necessarily pass an object with a `results` key. That depends on the API that you're using. The Twitter API passes an object with a `results` key, but a vanilla Backbone application will just pass an array of Models.

Answer (score 0):

When you validate your model, check for `model.silent` and only validate if that doesn't exist.

So you do the following when you want to fetch a model:

```
var test = new MyModel({ id: '123', silent: true }); 

// in your Model validate function
validate: function(attrs) {
  if (!attrs.silent) {
    // validate logic here
  }
}
```

Then you can fetch the model. After you get your model you can unset silent.